# Python Scrapy ValueError(f"No <form> element found in {response}")

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrap data from all pages but after scraping first page it showing an error

The code I wrote is as below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from ..items import PracticeItem
    
class Practice(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/login']
    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('form input::attr(value)').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
            'csrf': token,
            'username': 'demo',
            'password': 'demo'
        }, callback=self.start_scraping)
    
    def start_scraping(self, response):
        items = PracticeItem()
        all_tags = response.css('div.quote')
        for x in all_tags:
            quote = x.css('span.text::text').extract()
            title = x.css('.author::text').extract()
            tag = x.css('.tag::text').extract()
            items["quote"] = quote
            items["title"] = title
            items["tag"] = tag
            yield items
        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

## However I get this:

this is what i am getting after crawling first page.

```
2022-04-06 00:04:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
2022-04-06 00:04:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\bse\data science\python\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "F:\BSE\Data Science\Python\pythonProject\practice\practice\spiders\pra.py", line 16, in parse
    return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
  File "f:\bse\data science\python\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 64, in from_response
    form = _get_form(response, formname, formid, formnumber, formxpath)
  File "f:\bse\data science\python\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 104, in _get_form
    raise ValueError(f"No <form> element found in {response}")
ValueError: No <form> element found in <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
2022-04-06 00:04:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score -1):

On this line:

```
yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

you're telling Scrapy to process NEXT page using `self.parse` callback (that logins to the site). But you need to process it using `self.start_scraping` callback instead:

```
yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.start_scraping)
```

Also I think that you need to move `items = PracticeItem()` inside a `for` loop...